# Is the backend part of an angular app, or seperate?

Tags: angular, frontend, backend

I have an angular app I built in VS Code.
I either use 'ng serve' for testing or 'ng build' for qa, and 'ng build --prod' for prod.

I am now getting into doing credit-card stuff with stripe.

Just so I am clear... the project which I ng builld, or ng serve..... is that only front-end?

Like, to do stripe am I going to need to also create a NodeJS server?

I guess, I originally thought angular had a backend (like when I am serving it), but now seeing how it builds to just JS filles, am I to understand my angular app is pure front-end?

and if I want functionality like payment\emailing\faxing\texting, that I will need a nodeJS backend?

Thank-you for the clarification.
Christopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe, as an example, maintains its own backend. But you also need an API Key for it, which would be stored on *your own backend*. This doesn't need to be Node; its just a HTTP server.

Angular is a frontend framework, and can be served from any HTTP server

> if I want functionality like payment\emailing\faxing\texting

Probably, yes, because you want to internalize the details of what services to communicate with in order to have these features